# Can you help me adding a lottie to a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I need help with adding a lottie animationView to a UIButton,
something like this -
[just ignore the hebrew text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3o6N.png)

I need the icon on the right here to be a lottie animation view.. Can't figure it out, don't know if it's at all possible, can someone try to help here?

Answer (score 1):

> I need the icon on the right here to be a lottie animation view..

First off, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Secondly, this shouldn't be that hard. Since the goal is to simply make the icon as a lottie animation view, you can either:

1. Subclass the `UIButton` - in this way you can put the animation view on top of the imageView of the button.
2. Add directly a lottie animation view on top of the button.

Personally, I think the first one should do the job and is actually a better method.